# Python script to split a file in two parts, name each one separately

Tags: python, data-processing

I'm trying to code up a map visualization using d3.js and crossfilter, right now I have a big file and some pernicious row that is breaking the whole thing.

I want to create a file to split my input data in two halves so I can narrow down the source of the problem and thereby eliminate it whilst preserving my sanity.

The input data looks like this:

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2ODE3ODgifQ.1u6YvzMuu_HbWqRaMwFd8zYNP43w7wYFnRbl5r2qSoY,C# Developer,Connectus,Chesterton,52.202499,0.131237,United Kingdom,statistics,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2ODk1ODIifQ.jxcx56YcDm-4nmB8VvoIGQKew4yquszeaPon60hcDKs,Senior Java Developer,Redhill,Godstow,51.784375,-1.308003,United Kingdom,java|metadata,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2OTEyMjIifQ.qK3xtYQDxRpKJkNargPu6Jef4njm2fSZnNIVulRHoqA,Software Development Manager,Spring Technology ,Woolstone,52.042198,-0.7047,United Kingdom,software development|sdlc|data analysis,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NDM1MzgifQ.pYnBX-APPdB3edTRC_M8x6usmBq_GfIxcdZOXSLJN04,Data Scientists Python R Scala Java or Matlab,Aspire Data Recruitment,East Boldon,54.94452,-1.42815,United Kingdom,data science|java|python|scala|matlab|analysis,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NzM4NTMifQ.mgRKEZh-0GLUXQmZ9Bp6H10haZNAieIKAH1uoWV63YU,Data Analyst - Programmatic Tech Company,Ultimate Asset Limited,London,51.50853,-0.12574,United Kingdom,data analysis|analysis|statistics,1
```

So then, in my idea I would evenly divide it such that subsequently I would have:

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2ODE3ODgifQ.1u6YvzMuu_HbWqRaMwFd8zYNP43w7wYFnRbl5r2qSoY,C# Developer,Connectus,Chesterton,52.202499,0.131237,United Kingdom,statistics,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2ODk1ODIifQ.jxcx56YcDm-4nmB8VvoIGQKew4yquszeaPon60hcDKs,Senior Java Developer,Redhill,Godstow,51.784375,-1.308003,United Kingdom,java|metadata,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2OTEyMjIifQ.qK3xtYQDxRpKJkNargPu6Jef4njm2fSZnNIVulRHoqA,Software Development Manager,Spring Technology ,Woolstone,52.042198,-0.7047,United Kingdom,software development|sdlc|data analysis,1
```

and this one:

```
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2OTEyMjIifQ.qK3xtYQDxRpKJkNargPu6Jef4njm2fSZnNIVulRHoqA,Software Development Manager,Spring Technology ,Woolstone,52.042198,-0.7047,United Kingdom,software development|sdlc|data analysis,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NDM1MzgifQ.pYnBX-APPdB3edTRC_M8x6usmBq_GfIxcdZOXSLJN04,Data Scientists Python R Scala Java or Matlab,Aspire Data Recruitment,East Boldon,54.94452,-1.42815,United Kingdom,data science|java|python|scala|matlab|analysis,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NzM4NTMifQ.mgRKEZh-0GLUXQmZ9Bp6H10haZNAieIKAH1uoWV63YU,Data Analyst - Programmatic Tech Company,Ultimate Asset Limited,London,51.50853,-0.12574,United Kingdom,data analysis|analysis|statistics,1
```

for instance.

Naming them with a convention such as `starting_input.csv` becomes:

`starting_input_a.csv`

and

`starting_input_b.csv`

and then afterwards when I want to run it again:

`starting_input_aa.csv`

and

`starting_input_ab.csv`

and so on.

Can you follow my idea?

I tried this:

```
splitLen = 20         # 20 lines per file
outputBase = 'output' # output.1.txt, output.2.txt, etc.

# This is shorthand and not friendly with memory
# on very large files, but it works.
input = open('input.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

at = 1
for lines in range(0, len(input), splitLen):
    # First, get the list slice
    outputData = input[lines:lines+splitLen]

    # Now open the output file, join the new slice with newlines
    # and write it out. Then close the file.
    output = open(outputBase + str(at) + '.txt', 'w')
    output.write('\n'.join(outputData))
    output.close()

    # Increment the counter
    at += 1
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I'd suggest making your question a little more specific if you hope to get a meaningful response. You say you want to "split [the] input data in two halves" but you haven't given any info. about what the input data is, how you want it split, what attempts (if any) you've made, what issues you ran into processing the data...etc.

Comment: If you have problem row, why not parse the file to find the row? What is the definition of `pernicious row`?

Comment: row that must be breaking the whole visualization- I tried parsing it to find the row but I don't know what I'm looking for exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint.

Just read the file twice. Once to get the line count and then again to get the top half and bottom half.

Simple example. Given your 5 line example input:

```
$ cat /tmp/f1.txt
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2ODE3ODgifQ.1u6YvzMuu_HbWqRaMwFd8zYNP43w7wYFnRbl5r2qSoY,C# Developer,Connectus,Chesterton,52.202499,0.131237,United Kingdom,statistics,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2ODk1ODIifQ.jxcx56YcDm-4nmB8VvoIGQKew4yquszeaPon60hcDKs,Senior Java Developer,Redhill,Godstow,51.784375,-1.308003,United Kingdom,java|metadata,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI2OTEyMjIifQ.qK3xtYQDxRpKJkNargPu6Jef4njm2fSZnNIVulRHoqA,Software Development Manager,Spring Technology ,Woolstone,52.042198,-0.7047,United Kingdom,software development|sdlc|data analysis,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NDM1MzgifQ.pYnBX-APPdB3edTRC_M8x6usmBq_GfIxcdZOXSLJN04,Data Scientists Python R Scala Java or Matlab,Aspire Data Recruitment,East Boldon,54.94452,-1.42815,United Kingdom,data science|java|python|scala|matlab|analysis,1
http://www.edsa-project.eu/adzuna/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzIjoia0EtLWlpVHhUMUNtSFM0SzE4TUVzUSIsImkiOiIzMzI4NzM4NTMifQ.mgRKEZh-0GLUXQmZ9Bp6H10haZNAieIKAH1uoWV63YU,Data Analyst - Programmatic Tech Company,Ultimate Asset Limited,London,51.50853,-0.12574,United Kingdom,data analysis|analysis|statistics,1
```

You can do something like this:

```
def divide(fn):
    # get total lines in file
    with open(fn) as f:
        lc=sum(1 for _ in f)

    with open(fn) as fin:
        # top half of file:
        for i, line in enumerate(fin):
            print line
            if i>=lc/2:
                break
        # middle
        print "======="
        # remainder
        for line in fin:
            print line
```

That will print 3 lines from the top of the file then the '=======' divider then that last 2 lines of the example.

Instead of printing, you can write to two files with 'a' and 'b' added to the base names. Reapply to the resulting files until you are done.

Comment: wow- bravo. for writing out to those files, do you know how to make the file name variable- so that it keeps appending to the name of the original file, instead of making a new file every time? do you know what I mean? would that work in conjunction with `open("adzuna_output.csv", 'w') as file_out`?

Comment: Sorry -- I do not follow you. Do you mean make the file name change which then changes the contents of the file?

Comment: BTW: If you are on a *nix system, you can use [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_%28Unix%29) to do this and `wc -l` to get the line count

Comment: aha- you did like a regex thing- like linux? in fact I am. yeah- so- I was thinking- it would be better to output the two approximate halves into different files, but it would be annoying to have to go and change the line in the code each time I want to run the programme, so maybe- I was thinking about a way to automate that- but- I guess it's completely tangential to the original question